# Scala: How to catch exceptions in child threads

Tags: scala, exception

I had thought that the `Try` catches cross-Thread exceptions as in example below. I guess not: so how do I catch exceptions in spawned child threads?

```
// Simple class that throws error
class Child extends Runnable {
  def run {
    val exception: Exception = new Exception("Foo")
    val i = 1
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/filefoobar.txt").mkString
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }
}
// spawn the class above
def Parent() = {
  val doit = Try {
    val t = new Thread(new Child)
    t.start
    t.join()
  }

  doit match {
    case Success(v) => println("uh oh did not capture error")
    case Failure(v) => println("good we caught the error")
  }
}
```

Output
scala> Parent()

```
Exception in thread "Thread-35" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/filefoobar.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
    at $line120.$read$$iw$$iw$Child.run(<console>:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
uh oh did not capture error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using Futures to handle result of async task

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val resultFuture: Future[Unit] = Future { new Child.run }
resultFuture.onComplete (result: Try[Unit] => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the child accesses to the file raises an exception which captures JRE and follows the default behaviour; print stack trace, then propagates exception to parent processes, which captures the Parent as you can see in your output.

What you could do is catching the exception in the child process and throw yourself the exception so the parent could handle it.

Comment: .Are you saying that if rewrite the Child as a try block and throw an exception if I catch an error, the Parent will get that exception? How do I "throw myself" the exception ? After all, in the code as it stands, an error is thrown and goes up the stack, and does not reach the parent. Throwing an error explicitly in child will do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set the exception and then rethrow it from the try:

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

def Parent() = {

  @volatile
  var maybeException: Option[Throwable] = None

  val doit = Try {
    val target = new Child
    val t = new Thread(target)
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler {
      override def uncaughtException(t: Thread, th: Throwable): Unit = {
        maybeException = Some(th)
      }
    })
    t.start()
    t.join()

    maybeException.foreach(th => throw th)
  }

  doit match {
    case Success(v) => println("uh oh did not capture error")
    case Failure(v) => println("good we caught the error")
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code does not quite compile. I get a <console>:34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Thread, Throwable) => Unit
 required: java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
           t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t: Thread, e: Throwable) => {
                                                                   ^

Comment: sorry not being lazy, I did try to fix it.

Comment: Looks like you're using Scala 2.11, my example was for 2.12 so I've updated so it works in 2.11.